# How do I get my .net maui app to appear in the device Share dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Often, apps have a "Share" button. When using other apps on my device which have the "Share" button (e.g. web browser, news apps, etc), when you tap this button it shows you a list of apps to share the URL with.

So, for example, I can be in Chrome, navigate to a page, tap Share, and from this I can select my email app to share the URL.

Any advice on how that can be implemented in Maui? I.e. I want my app to appear in the Share dialog.

Thanks

P.S. apologies for the poor wording before ;)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/data/share

Comment: Isn't that for if I want to share from my app - not to my app?

Comment: Then update your question to reflect that, because the way it is written, it sounds like you want to share something from your app.

Comment: @Julian - I literally say 'When using the web browser...'. How can you mistake that as sounding like I want to share something from the app?

Comment: Read the introduction of your question again and then read the actual question right after. It reads like you want to implement something like the share functionality of the browser. You didn't specify that you want your app to be the receiver.

Comment: @Julian ok fair point. I think I will just re-word the whole thing...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me in Android platform. I can launch my app one of two ways:

---

###### Navigate to https://www.ivsoftware.net/interceptor-test.html and click the button:

[image: deep-linking]

---

##### From this or any other web page, click the Google Chrome Share Icon instead:

[image: share icon]

---

Here's the [Android Intent Filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) code.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using url_interceptor;

namespace url_interceptor.Platforms.Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "UrlInterceptorActivity", Exported =true)]
    [IntentFilter(
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
        { 
            Intent.CategoryDefault, 
            Intent.CategoryBrowsable 
        },
        DataSchemes = new[] 
        {
            "net.ivsoftware.demo" 
        })]

    [IntentFilter(
        new[]
        { Intent.ActionSend },
        Categories = new[]
        {
            Intent.CategoryDefault,
        },
        DataMimeType = "text/plain"
    )]
    public class UrlInterceptorActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent intent = Intent;
            var uri = intent.Data;
            StartMainActivity();
            Task
                .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                .GetAwaiter()
                .OnCompleted(() =>
                {
                    switch (this.Intent.Action)
                    {
                        case Intent.ActionView:
                            if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionView)
                            {
                                var uri = intent.Data;
                                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Interceptor", "Deep Link Button", "OK");
                            }
                            break;
                        case Intent.ActionSend:
                            var link = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);
                            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Interceptor", $"Shared Link: '{link}'", "OK");
                            break;
                    }
                });
            Finish(); 
        }

        private void StartMainActivity()
        {
            Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

---

iOS has a similar mechanism for intercepting URLs but I haven't tested this particular action.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think I might be missing something but this looks more like a way to do deep linking from a web page into an app. I am wanting my app to appear on the Share dialog. Have I misunderstood what this is doing?

Comment: thanks for the update. Where you have "From this or any other web page, click the Google Chrome Share Icon instead..." - I can see your app "UrlInterceptorActivity" shows in the share dialog. That is the thing I can't get to work. I downloaded your repo and installed the app but it doesn't show in the share dialog.

Comment: Please [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/url-interceptor.git) or pull the latest commit. Alternatively, copy-paste the intent filter shown in my updated post. Your edited question makes it plainly clear what you want to do and so thank you for the helpful edit.

Comment: For iOS, the _mechanism_ is clear (but troublesome...). You make a Share Extension, and that extension uses the custom URL scheme (e.g. "com.ivsoftware.demo") to invoke the app. So the extension is a broker that takes the Safari share link and deep-links to the CFBundleURLScheme defined in Info.plist. But I'm having a heck of a time getting the Share Extension to deploy in MAUI and I see others are, too. The thing you're asking is VERY WORTHWHILE IMO and so I'm going to keep plugging on that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I got your latest commit and I can now see it working in Android. I am now running into this problem (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13861) when I try to navigate from the url interceptor code. Typical Maui!! But thanks - 1 step closer! I'm no further forward with iOS either.

Comment: FWIW we have [Vladislav Antonyuk](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main) appearing to succeed in iOS but he's building in the [now deprecated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/) Visual Studio for Mac which I haven't tried. [see full github.io article](https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Extend-.NET-MAUI-application-with-iOS-Extensions/) _and_ there's also https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/3289 so pray for us all.

Comment: I just tried that. Doesn't seem to work. Looks like an old Xamarin hack...

Answer (score -1):

MAUI provides **IShare** interface for such purpose. Just use **RequestAsync** method to show list of apps to share.

```cs
await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
{
    Uri = "https://test.com",
    Title = "Share Web Link"
});
```

More info can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/data/share?tabs=android

Comment: I might be misunderstanding that, but isn't that the other way round? That looks like it is used if I want to share links FROM my app - not if I want my app to be the recipient of a share request.

Comment: P.S. if I have misunderstood, where would I put that code in the app? That information is missing.

Comment: I see, looks like I misunderstood your question. It's indeed other way round. Anyway, looks like somebody else has answered your question the right way already.